# не могу импорировать в проект pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5, gui, pyqt

у меня такая ошибка при выводе кода:

**qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "" This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.**

код:

```
import sys

def applicacion():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("affowfuowhf")
    window.setGeometry(300, 250, 350, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    applicacion() 


буду благодарен помощи:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить строчку `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow`
Если конечно у вас добавлена библиотека PyQt5
вот как добавить библиотеку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow  # ++
import sys

def applicacion():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("affowfuowhf")
    window.setGeometry(300, 250, 350, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    applicacion()
```

Comment: спасибо, только теперь новая ошибка: DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, на этот я ответил